how to preg_match_all html tag in php
I am trying to get the data in the html code.
I tried to do something but it didn't work. Can you help me?
$metin = "<div><b>bla bla bla</b>/<div>";
$pattern = '<div><b>(.*?)</b></div>';
preg_match_all($pattern,$metin,$haslar);
print_r($haslar);


Your HTML appears to be faulty, /<div> instead of </div> at the end. And your regex pattern needs delimiters. (And you should rather not use regular expressions to attempt to parse HTML in the first place, https://stackoverflow.com/q/6751105/1427878, https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747/1427878)

"it didn't work" - what does that mean? Why not parse HTML with a proper HTML parser?
